# What is a managed identity (MSI)?

Tags: azure-managed-identity

The Azure docs define managed identities as

> An identity in Azure Active Directory (more specifically, a special type of service principal) that is automatically managed by Azure. You typically use managed identities when developing cloud applications to manage the credentials for authenticating to Azure services.

but still not sure what they are.

Comment: See also [service principal vs managed identity answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75893414/1498178).

Comment: Managed identities for Azure resources is the new name for the service formerly known as Managed Service Identity (MSI).
See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-faq?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-4015686

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 0. Name

> **[Managed identities for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-faq)** is the new name for the service formerly known as **Managed Service Identity (MSI)**.

<sup>Thank you @[WillHuang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/910074/will-huang)!</sup>

### 1. Definition

> A **managed identity** (MSI<sup>**1**</sup>) is [a special kind of *service principal*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview#managed-identity-types) that is assigned to [an Azure resource that supports wielding managed identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-status) to access other Azure services / resources ***without credentials***.

### 2. Terms

Going to use the following terms (some arbitrarily chosen) here:

- **MSI resource**: [an Azure resource that support having (or endowed with) managed identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-status)
- **target resource**: an Azure resource that the **MSI resource** is trying to access
- **identity**: [Azure Active Directory identities](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/demystifying-service-principals-managed-identities/#azure-ad-identity)); a quick overview:

  ```
  security
  principal
      │
      ├─► user
      │
      ├─► group
      │                  managed
      └─► service  ────► identity
          principal      (MSI)
  ```

  (See also [this answer] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/75850555/1498178).)
- **service principal**:

  > A security identity used by applications or services to access specific Azure resources. You can think of it as a user identity (username and password or certificate) for an application.
  > <sup>(from [Steps to assign an Azure role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-steps)</sup>)

  or

  > "*An application whose tokens can be used to authenticate and grant access to specific Azure resources from a user-app, service or automation tool, when an organization is using Azure Active Directory*"
  >
  > In essence, by using a Service Principal, you avoid creating “fake users” (we would call them service account in on-premises Active Directory…) in Azure AD to manage authentication when you need to access Azure Resources.
  > <sup>(from [Demystifying Service Principals – Managed Identities](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/demystifying-service-principals-managed-identities/#service-principal))</sup>

#### 3. Properties of managed identities

TL;DR

|  | **user-assigned MSI** | **system-assigned MSI** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **What if MSI resource is deleted?** | unassigned and remains intact | deleted |
| **How many can be assigned to an MSI resource?** | any number | only 1 |
| **How many can be authorized on a target resource?** | any number | any number |
| **Can it be authorized on multiple target resources at the same time?** | yes | yes |

<sup>([MSI resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-status) =/= managed identity)</sup>

The relationship between [**MSI resources**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-status) and **managed identities** is similar to boxes with labels or people having names & nicknames / aliases:

An [**MSI resource**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-status)

- can have ONE **system-assigned** managed identity

  (such as a person is only allowed to have one legal name)
- can be assigned MANY **user-assigned** managed identities

  (such as a person can be known by different nicknames by their associates)

Not sure what the intention was with this design choice, but this allows one to create multiple identities for an [**MSI resource**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-status) (or, put another way, an [**MSI resource**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-status) can assume multiple identities), each of which could be authorized to perform different operations on **target resources**. (A target resource can also authorize multiple MSIs; see "Examples" section below.)

When an [**MSI resource**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-status) is deleted,

- the **system-assigned** MSI is deleted with it
- the **user-assigned** managed identities will remain (these will only get unassigned)

#### 3.1 How come no credentials are needed?

Because [access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens) are used instead. The [general workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-linux-vm-access-arm) summed up:

1. Assign a managed identity to an [**MSI resource**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-status).
2. Grant access to that managed identity on the **target resource**.
3. Request an [access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens)
4. Use the token through / from the [**MSI resource**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-status) to perform actions on the **target resource**.
5. When the token expires, go to Step 3.

See "Example A (with commands)" section below for the specifics.

### 4. Examples<sup>**2**</sup>

> NOTE
> In the examples below, the type of the **target resources** is an [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview), that supports access control (IAM) and access policies to authorize MSIs; this is a tricky topic, but [this Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60625098/difference-between-access-control-and-access-policies-in-key-vault) has a great explanation.

#### 4.1 Example A (overview)

1. Set up a virtual machine (`AZVM`) with **system-assigned** MSI (`AZVM-id`).
2. Authorize this identity in an Azure key vault (`AZKV`).
3. SSH into `AZVM`.
4. Get an access token.
5. Perform operations on `AZKV` that `AZVM` (through its `AZVM-id`) is permitted to do (in **Step 2.**).

For the specifics, see "Example A (with commands)" section below.

```
                          (e.g., REST API)
                   ┌── ── ── ── ── ── ─── ─── ─── ─── ──┐
                   │                                    │
         ┌─AZVM─── │ ─┐                ┌─AZKV────────┐  │
         │            │                │             │  │
         │         │  │                │             │
                   ▼  │                │             │  │
   ┌─ ── ───(service) │                │ + secrets   │  │
   │                  │                │ + keys      │
         │            │                    + key1       │
   │     └────────────┘          ┌── ── ─► + key2 ── ───┘
   │         identities=         │
   └── ─── ───►[ AZVM-id ]─── ───┘     │             │
                                       │             │
                                       └─────────────┘
```

#### 4.2 Example B

1. Set up (existing) virtual machines (`AZVM-<n>`) with **system-assigned** managed identities (`AZVM-id-<n>`).
2. Assign additional user-assigned MSIs (`AZVM-user-id-<n>`; [docs: create & assign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-manage-user-assigned-managed-identities?pivots=identity-mi-methods-azp))
3. Authorize the above MSIs on multiple a key vaults (`AZKV-<n>`).

```
                                   ┌─────────────────────────────┐
                                   │                             │
                                   │         ┌──AZKV-1────────┐  │
              ┌──AZVM-1─────┐      │         │                │  │
              │             │      │         │                │  │
              │             │      │         │ + keys         │  │
           ┌──── (service) ◄───────┘         │    + key-1     │  │
           │  │             │           ┌──────►  + key-2 ───────┘
           │  │             │           │    │                │ 
           │  │             │           │    │                │
           │  └─────────────┘           │    │ + secrets      │
           │      identities=           │    │   + secret-1   │
           │        [ AZVM-id-1         │  ┌──── + password ◄─────┐
           │        , AZVM-user-id-1    │  │ │                │   │
           │        , AZVM-user-id-2    │  │ │                │   │
           └──────► , AZVM-user-id-3 ───┘  │ └────────────────┘   │
                    ]                      │                      │
                                           │                      │
                                           │ ┌──AZKV-2────────┐   │
                                           │ │                │   │
           ┌─────AZVM-2─────┐              │ │ + secrets      │   │
           │                │              │ │   + secret-2   │   │
           │                │              │ │   + password   │   │
     USER ────┐◄───────────────────────────┘ │                │   │
           │  │             │                │ + keys         │   │
           │  │             │     ┌───────────── + key-3 ◄──────┐ │
           │  │ ┌──(service) ◄────┘          │   + key-4      │ │ │
           │  │ │           │                │                │ │ │
           └──│─│───────────┘                └────────────────┘ │ │
              │ │ identities=                                   │ │
              │ └──►[ AZVM-id-2  ───────────────────────────────┘ │
              └────►, AZVM-user-id-3 ─────────────────────────────┘
                    ]
```

#### 4.3 Example A (with commands)

1. **Endow a virtual machine (the MSI resource) with *system-assigned* managed identity**

   When using the Portal, this can be done by going to the "Identity" menu item in a virtual machine's page on the Portal (see [Demystifying Service Principals – Managed Identities](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/demystifying-service-principals-managed-identities/) or [Configure managed identities for Azure resources on a VM using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-portal-windows-vm) in the docs).

   [image: Screenshot from Azure portal of a virtual machine's page highlighting the "Identity" item in the menu.]
2. **Grant access to the *system-assigned* managed identity on the key vault (the target resource).**

   When using the Portal, this can be done by clicking on "Access policies" menu item, and then on the "+ Create" button. The 1st page will ask to choose what privileges one wants to assign to the policy, the 2nd page will ask which identity to be used so choose the system-assigned MSI in Step 1. See more at [Azure Key Vault security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/security-features) in the docs.
3. **SSH into the VM in Step 1.**

   ```
   ssh -l <username> -i <private_key> 1.2.3.4
   ```
4. **Request a token.**

   Using the [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/) via `curl`.

   (The [`jq` command](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is not necessary; it just makes the output easier to read.)

   ```
   $ curl "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://vault.azure.net" \
       -H Metadata:true  | jq

   {
     "access_token": "...",
     "client_id": "12345678-9abc-def1-2345-6789abcdef12",
     "expires_in": "84162",
     "expires_on": "1680292962",
     "ext_expires_in": "86399",
     "not_before": "1680206262",
     "resource": "https://vault.azure.net",
     "token_type": "Bearer"
   }
   ```
5. **Use the token.**

   For example, [to list the keys in the key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/keys/get-keys/get-keys?tabs=HTTP) (again, using the [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/) via `curl`):

   ```
   $ curl https://my-project.vault.azure.net/keys?api-version=7.3 \
       -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN-FROM-STEP-4>" | jq

   {
     "value": [
       {
         "kid": "https://my-project.vault.azure.net/keys/keyname",
         "attributes": {
           "enabled": true,
           "created": 1679939404,
           "updated": 1679939404,
           "recoveryLevel": "Recoverable+Purgeable",
           "recoverableDays": 90,
           "exportable": false
         },
         "tags": {}
       }
     ],
     "nextLink": null
   }
   ```

To avoid copying `access_token` manually:

```
$ access_token=$(curl "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://vault.azure.net"  -H Metadata:true  | jq '.access_token' -r)
$
$ curl https://my-project.vault.azure.net/keys?api-version=7.3 \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}" | jq
```

---

##### Footnotes

[1]: From [note in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview#:%7E:text=Managed%20identities%20for%20Azure%20resources%20is%20the%20new%20name%20for%20the%20service%20formerly%20known%20as%20Managed%20Service%20Identity%20(MSI)): "*Managed identities for Azure resources is the new name for the service formerly known as Managed Service Identity (MSI).*" Decided to keep using this because every single Azure API implementation and 3rd party application that I used thus far referred to **managed identity** as MSI.

[2]: Loosely based on the one in [Demystifying Service Principals – Managed Identities](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/demystifying-service-principals-managed-identities/).

##### Notes

- Figures were created with [asciiflow](https://asciiflow.com/#/).
- Finding MSIs on the Portal

  **User-assigned** MSIs have a their own sub-category "Managed Identities", but this won't show **system-assigned** ones. The latter need to be searched individually.
- Resource groups and MSIs

  This is only based on my experiences on the Portal, but it seems that **system-assigned** MSIs don't belong to a resource group (or they are hidden). That is, **user-assigned** ones show it clearly when called up, but couldn't find this info for **system-assigned** MSIs, and it doesn't make sense. The latter are tied tightly to the [**MSI resource**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-status) so I went to the particular resource's resource group, listed all members, but they also don't show up there. Weird.

Comment: That is a whole lot of/way too much details, I think you should really emphasis the fact that you do not need to manage any secrets at all and keep it short. Many docs avaible regarding the details you've added in your answer.

Comment: @PeterBons Yeah, it is way too lengthy, but I like that most relevant stuff with links to the Azure docs are in one place - and my handwritten notes started to pile up. The Azure docs are super fragmented, and found some definitions, examples, code snippets to a certain topic at places that are not even germane to the topic in question.